# Toggle Show/Hide Google Marker with 1 button

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to toggle a button which will hide/show the google marker placed in the map. I have been searching for an answer on SOF but all offered array method. I am wondering if it is possible to do it without array.

```
      function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: 1.3420894594991328, lng: 103.83490918886719},
    });

        var ntuc = {
        lat: 1.32805676,
        lng: 103.9216584
    };

        var ntucmap = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: ntuc,
        map: map,
        icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-stars.png'
    });

   }

      function toggleNTUCmap() {
    if (!ntucmap.getVisible()) {
        ntucmap.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        ntucmap.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
```

Button

```
<button class="button-oj pure-button" onclick="toggleNTUCmap()">
          <i class="fas fa-hospital"></i> NTUC</button>
```

For function toggleNTUCmap(), I have tried the following which still won't work.

```
ntucmap.setMap(ntucmap.getMap() ? null : map);
```

Comment: I think this might be because it is not rerendering have you tried passing an alternative property to it or setting it as state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Adds a marker at the center of the map.
var ntuc = {lat: 1.32805676, lng: 103.9216584};
addMarker(ntuc);
setMapOnAll(null);

// Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-stars.png'
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

// Show/Hide Markers
var counter = 0;

function toggleMarkers() {
    if (counter == 0) {
        setMapOnAll(map);
        counter = 1;
    } else {
        setMapOnAll(null);
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

In the end, I used array to save all the markers. Based on the button which user used to toggle, it will determine whether it marker(s) will be shown on the map or not.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do something like this?

```
    function clearMap(map) {
    for(var i = 0; i<ntucmap.length; i++){
      ntucmap[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
```

and for the show part

```
function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ntucmap.length; i++) {
      ntucmap[i].setMap(map);
    }
}
```

Then to have it in one button you can keep a counter with your button and when it's even do one function when it's odd do the other?

Comment: Hi @mrdeadsven, how to do a counter for button?

Comment: @Eddie just create an variable 'int counter = 0'. and then in your onclick function first thing you do is counter++. and then a simple if else. something like if(counter%2 == 0){ clearMap(map) }else{ setMapOnAll(map) }.

Comment: @Eddie No problem, glad I could help!